# Update style of a single angular mat-badge

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

So in my code I have mat badges in two different places,

```
<div matBadge="0" class="first"></div>
<div matBadge="1" class="second"></div>
```

I want to apply the following style,

```
.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-overlap.mat-badge-after .mat-badge-content {
  right: 4px;
}
```

But I want the style to get applied only to the badge on the first div. How can
I do that?

Comment: In two different places? Are you sure the DOM structure is the same?

Comment: You may want to try this:

`.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-overlap.mat-badge-after.first .mat-badge-content { right: 15px; }`

Output:

https://angular-dfxdsc.stackblitz.io

Comment: That worked thank you so much. If you add it as an answer I will approve it. @m4n0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-overlap.mat-badge-after.first .mat-badge-content { /* Using first inside the multiple class selector */
  right: 15px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Stackblitz Demo]

[Stackblitz Demo](https://angular-dfxdsc.stackblitz.io)